# How to push changes made to a wordpress site back into a github repo? (not the other way around)

Tags: wordpress, github

We're redesigning our entire website into Wordpress b/c the marketing team don't know how to code. However I'd like to have all changes made on the Wordpress site - THROUGH the Wordpress interface, pushed back into a github repo so we have everything in the same place and I can track changes / updates / versions.

I searched around but only saw guides that do this the other way around, which is have github updates pushed into a Wordpress site. I actually don't want that since the people who are going to be making changes should be making them on Wordpress (that was the whole point b/c they don't know how to code).

So how do I make it so that all changes made on Wordpress through the Wordpress interface get pushed into a github repo? Is this something where I just have to write a script that "backs up" the changes? Or is there something smarter?

Comment: [VersionPress](https://versionpress.com/) sounds like a good fit for this, might want to check it out.

Comment: YES this is what I need, thanks @cabrerahector !!!